# Using images from Instagram on my e-commerce website

Tags: terms-of-service, social-media

We are in the process of making an e-commerce website selling our own established brand of makeup. However we would like to use the instagram API to fetch images that use a specific hashtag like #ourproduct.

What we would like to do with these images is have something like a gallery of "others who bought this" so that new customers can see content from our other customers before deciding.

Is this legal or violating the TOS of Instagram? I know Instagram says that users' images are "all rights reserved". But isn't it implied consent by using our hashtag?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this legal or violating the TOS of instagram?

It’s violating the terms.

> But isn't it implied consent by using our hashtag?

First, nobody owns a hashtag.

Second, no.